# Recommended Precaculus + Calculus books

Tags: soft-question

I'm learning Algebra, and the next course in school is Precalculus and Calculus. And according to most reliable sources, Precalculus and Calculus are going to be really difficult.

So.. I'm wondering

> **Question:** Are there any recommended Precalculus and Calculus books (that go together) that you guys suggest?

---

What I mean by "go together" means that right after you read the Precalculus book, the Calculus book goes right where the Precalculus book left off. As if they "go together".

I prefer books where it's gradual, but they still cover everything (or the gist) you need to know about the courses. Bonus if the solutions are understandable!

Comment: Stewart's Calculus is a standard text used by many American universities.

Comment: @JackyChong Is there a PDF version online? Because I've noticed that for some books, there's no such thing as an online PDF of the book (for some reason) :/

Comment: I don't think I am allowed to tell you that on this site.

Comment: @JackyChong Wait why? Guidelines? Restrictions?

Comment: I'm a huge fan of the Larson Hostetler Edwards series for precalculus and calculus books